# Dependent Drop Down doesn't work properly

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, apache

Basically i'm a new explorer which just started learning PHP & MySQL, what's I'm trying to do is make a dependent drop down.
The first drop down was alright, but the second drop down wasn't link with the first drop-down, anyone can help with this please?

Thanks.

**index.php**

```
<?php
  $connect = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "root", "carsdb");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <body>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Car Selection</title>  
<div class = "container" style = "width:700px;">

    <form action = "" method = "POST">

    <div class = "jumbotron">
  <h1>Car Selection</h1><br>

  <label>Brand:</label> <select id = "Brand">
      <option value = "">Car Brand Selection</option>
        <?php
          $query = "SELECT Brand FROM Brand";
          $result = $connect->query($query);
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
              echo "<option value = '{$row["Brand"]}'>{$row["Brand"]}</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select><br>

    <label>Model:</label> <select id = "Model">
        <option value = "">Car Model Selection</option>
    </select><br><br>

      <input type = "submit" name="insert" class = "btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Next">

  </form>

</div>
</div>  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      $("#Brand").change(function(){
        bid=$(this).val();
        $.post("fetch.php",{id:bid}, function(data){
          $("#Model").html(data);
        });
      }); 
</script>

    </body>    
</html>
```

**fetch.php**

```
<?php
$connect = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "root", "carsdb");
$query = "SELECT Model FROM Model where CODE = {$_POST["id"]}";
$result = $connect->query($query);
echo "<option value = ''>Select</option>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value = '{$row["Code"]}'>{$row["Model"]}</option>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: You should also do some debugging. Does your ajax request even get executed? Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: A couple of more notes: 1. Wrap your jquery code inside `$(function() {  ...your code... })` to make sure that it won't get executed before the document is fully loaded. 2. Properly define JS variables before you use them. Change `bid=$(this).val();` to `var bid=$(this).val();`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for reply, unfortunately it doesn't show and syntax or error message. I'm still exploring PHP :P

Comment: I'm not talking about PHP. I'm talking about your browsers console (in development tools) that shows you any javascript errors. Please do proper debugging (as previous mentioned) and update your question with the result. We can't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than--

```
echo "<option value = '{$row["Code"]}'>{$row["Model"]}</option>";
```

Try it ----

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['Code'].'">'.$row['Model'].'</option>';
```